# EndInvoke's arguments

Tags: .net, delegates, iasyncresult, asynchronous

I have a delegate foo, I call BeginInvoke on it and retrieve the IAsyncResult into a var bar.

I then call EndInvoke(bar) and everything is happy.

Why do I have to pass bar to endinvoke? what exactly is going on that demands this? I realize Endinvoke is mandatory to clear possible resource leaks, but this parameter makes no sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it makes perfect sense. You could have invoked the delegate multiple times - how is `EndResult` meant to know which invocation you're talking about? The `IAsyncResult` is basically encapsulating the asynchronous task.

If you've been looking at any of the newer stuff, think of IAsyncResult as a *little* bit like an opaque version of `Task`.